# how to declare multiple variables with the same value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

in order to prevent creating every single variable with same type I declared them this way:

```js
  data () {
    return {
      today,tomorrow: new Date(),
    };
  },
```

all I get in my intellij terminal is an error

> > error  'today' is not defined  no-undef

have I mistaken the syntax or the process is not possible ?

Comment: It's not possible in an object literal. You need a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an object, in an object by using the comma `,` you are listing different properties of the object, since you don't define today before typing the comma, you tell the object that today is now undefined.

It is better to just declare both properties or not use an object.

```js
function data() {
  let sameVariable = new Date();
  return {
    today: sameVariable,
    tomorrow: sameVariable,
  };
}
```

This way you can now acces the variables with obj.today and obj.tomorrow

Maybe take a look in how objects work (thats when returning something with `{...}`)
You are returning an Object in your example

Comment: creating a third variable is better than initializing today & tomorrow with = new Date(); ?

Comment: If you type `new Date()` in both declarations you would have 2 dates that are referenced, by declaring the variable before hand u basically tell the code when looking either at `today` or `tomorrow` to look in the same place (which here is where sameVariable is) on in the storage. This is just optimization. So as long as both dates are the same and you don't say `tomorrow` = something else now, you use the same storage and thus save some ;) If you are interested in this you can look up references / pointers / storage

Comment: And yes inside an object there would be no other way to have to properties be the same thing unless you declare it beforehand (then they are exactly the same) or declare the same thing individually to both (then they look the same but don't share the same reference storage)

Comment: well later in my code I have appended tomorrow with 1 day so using the same reference is not a solution imo

Answer (score 0):

Simple. you can't. In JS object and JSON syntaxt you can't declare and init many varialbes in one expression.

if you need many vars with the same value, just return it from setup function.

```js
setup(){
   const now = new Date();
   return {
      today: now,
      tomorow: now
   }
}
```

you can create it in "create" function.

```js
created(){
   this.today = new Date();
   this.tomorrow = new Date();
}
```

But be aware. Date is instance of Data class. So if two variables points to it, then you have to remember that changing props of today will affect tomorrow. Eg. if your  today and tommorow variables points to one Date object then today.setHours will affect tommorow  as well.